# onClick transition and toggle visibility on div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here I want to create a dropdown form with transition effect on click of  element, onClick it triggers the transition but when I click again it doesn't triggers the transition instead it just hides the div element....
Demo: http://tryitnow.net16.net/

See below:

function:

```
<script>

$(function() {

    $("#login").click(function() {
        var visi= $(".User-Login").css('visibility');

        if(visi=="visible") {
            $(".User-Login").toggleClass("box-colap");
            $(".User-Login").css('visibility','hidden');    
        }
        else {
            $(".User-Login").css('visibility','visible');
            $(".User-Login").toggleClass("box-change"); 
        }       
    });
});
```

html:

```
<table class="MainMenu" style="width:100%;background-color:white" align="center">
<a href="#">Home</a>
        &nbsp;
        &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td>
        <a href="#">How It Works </a>
        </td>
        <td>
        <a href="#"> Features</a>
        </td>
        <td>
        <a href="#"> Why Us </a>
        </td>
        <td>
        <a href="#"> Sign Up </a>
        </td>
        <td>
        <a id="login" href="javascript:void(0);"> Login </a>
        </td>
</table>
```

css:

```
 .User-Login {  

visibility:hidden;
position:absolute;
left:1150px;    


background:black;
-webkit-transition:  height 2s ease;  
-moz-transition:  height 2s ease;  
-o-transition: height 2s ease;  
-ms-transition: height 2s ease;  
transition:, height 2s ease;  
overflow:hidden;


height:10px;

 top:90px;

}  

.box-change {   
height: 250px;  
}

.box-colap {
height:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two simple solutions from css3 you don't even need jquery

[fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/R8zca/4/)

[fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/L7Paa/)

both are using css3

here's the actual css code for sliding

```
div{
display:block;
height:120px;
width:120px;
background:red;
}

.hideUp{
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background:blue;
    display:block;
    -webkit-transition:all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition:all 1s ease;
}

.hideUp:focus{
    top:-200px;
}
```

and the html

```
<a href="#" tabindex="-1" class="hideUp"><div><p>CLICK TO MOVE</p></div></a>
```

:)